# code shows unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

hy!
I am trying to run a jquery shake and hide effect.
I simple create a login form consist of 2 fields.
I put condition that if user will login with wrong username and password, it will shake or bounce toward left, otherwise it displays a home.php page with hide and show effect.
But whenever i tried to login with true or wrong username and password, it does not bounce. It always gives hide and show effect.
Please see my code, why it's behaving like this.

index.php

```
<?php  
 session_start();
 print_r($_SESSION);
 if(isset($_SESSION["username"]))  
 {  
      header("location:home.php");  
 }  
 ?>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">  
           <meta charset="utf-8">  
           <title>Webslesson Tutorial</title>  
           <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>  
           <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
           <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>  
           <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
           <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
           <style>  
           #box  
           {  
                width:100%;  
                max-width:500px;  
                border:1px solid #ccc;  
                border-radius:5px;  
                margin:0 auto;  
                padding:0 20px;  
                box-sizing:border-box;  
                height:270px;  
           }  
           </style>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <div class="container">  
                <h2 align="center">How to Use Ajax with PHP for Login with Shake Effect</h2><br /><br />  
                <div id="box">  
                     <br />  
                     <form method="post">  
                          <div class="form-group">  
                               <label>Username</label>  
                               <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" />  
                          </div>  
                          <div class="form-group">  
                               <label>Password</label>  
                               <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" />  
                          </div>  
                          <div class="form-group">  
                               <input type="button" name="login" id="login" class="btn btn-success" value="Login" />  
                          </div>  
                          <div id="error"></div>  
                     </form>  
                     <br />  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#login').click(function(){  
           var username = $('#username').val();  
           var password = $('#password').val();  
           if($.trim(username).length > 0 && $.trim(password).length > 0)  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"login.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{username:username, password:password},  
                     cache: false,  
                     beforeSend:function()  
                     {  
                          $('#login').val("connecting...");  
                     },  
                     success:function(data)  
                     {  
                          if(data)  
                          {  
                               $("body").load("home.php").hide().fadeIn(1500);  
                          }  
                          else  
                          {  
                               //shake animation effect.  
                               var options = {  
                                    distance: '40',  
                                    direction:'left',  
                                    times:'3'  
                               }  
                               $("#box").effect("shake", options, 800);  
                               $('#login').val("Login");  
                               $('#error').html("<span class='text-danger'>Invalid username or Password</span>");  
                          }  
                     }  
                });  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                return false;  
           }  
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```

login.php

```
<?php  
 session_start();  
 include_once './include/db_connection.php';
 if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))  
 {  
      $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["username"]);  
      $password = md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["password"]));  
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM signup WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'";  
      $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);  
      $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);  
      if($num_row > 0)  
      {  
           $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  
           $_SESSION["username"] = $data["username"];  
           echo $data["username"];  
      }  
 }  
 ?>
```

home.php

```
<?php  
 session_start();  
 if(!isset($_SESSION["username"]))  
 {  
      header("location: index.php");  
 }  
 echo '<h1 align="center">'.$_SESSION["username"].' - Welcome to Home Page</h1>';  
 echo '<p align="center"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>';  
 ?>
```

Comment: Based on the rules, it seems the question is from the **off-topic** area "[*Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)"

Comment: @Farside
I am so confused that's why, i posted the question what i understand .

Answer (score 0):

In your `success` callback, the data parameter is a string, right? Why are you checking if it is falsy? If it contains any whitespace, which it probably does even if the user doesn't log in successfully then it will be equivalent to true, not false.

Answer (score 0):

You need return from login.php both values = true or false. Cause you always get some data in your var.

login.php

```
if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){
  echo 'true'; // you send here $data["username"];
} else {
  echo 'false';
}
```

And in js code on success event you check:

```
success:function(data){
  if(data=='false'){
     // somethings wrong
  } else {
     // welcome
  }
}
```